Can't get full data log from TensorBoard (Only 1000)
When I download the scalar data from TensorBoard, it only exports 1000 steps.
The tutorial online requires modifying "scalar_metadata.PLUGIN_NAME" in application.py.
However, after I opened application.py following the path, I couldn't find the parameter "scalar_metadata.PLUGIN_NAME".
How can I solve this problem and export all the steps that I have, Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example
